# Shared single variable for list?

Tags: c++, pointers, static

This problem is a little difficult to describe, so bear with me if it isn't clear.

I want to implement a doubly-linked list with a single, universally accessible [to the items inside] Head, End and Iter pointers - this would greatly reduce memory overhead and processing/accessing times...

Static *almost* fulfills this role - except, it's shared by *all* classes of the same type - which what I don't want [as I might have multiple doubly-linked lists - I need one per list, not one per class]. So what I need is something similar to static, except it's localised to different declarations.

Head/Node methods become complicated (notably as it uses templates) and I want to avoid this at all costs. Head just ends up having duplicate functions of Node [so Node is accessible], which seems a waste and added complexity just to have three local-universal variables.

What I'd like is something similar to this:

```
class Test
{
 private:
  static Test *Head; //Single universal declaration!
  static Test *End;
  static Test *Iter;
 //etc etc
};
```

Except...

```
Test A; //Set of 'static' variables 'unique' to A
Test B; //Set of 'static' variables 'unique' to B
```

I am willing to entertain any and all solutions to the problem, but please avoid complicated solutions - this is meant as an improvement and needs to be quick and simple to implement.

**Additional Information [as requested]:**
There isn't a 'problem' per se [aside in terms of avoiding overhead and design] - this is setting the frame-work/ground-work for several other classes/functions to build on. So the class needs to be able to handle multiple roles/variables/classes - for this, it has to be templated [although this isn't entirely relevant].

One [of many] of it's main roles is storing individual characters [loaded from files] in seperate Nodes. Given the size can vary, it has to be dynamic. However, as one of it's roles involve loading from files, it can't be an array [as reading the file to work out number of arguments, characters etc causes harddrive/access bottlenecks]. So...

...Singly-linked lists would allow a character to be [easily] added [to the list] on each pass that gets a character [and counted at the same time - solving two problems in one]. The problem is singly-linked lists are very hard to [safely] delete, and navigation is one way. Which is a problem as this hinders search functionality, and notably, the intended multipurpose role...

...So the conclusion is it has to be a doubly-linked list. I don't like the STL or standard lists as I have no idea of their efficiency or safety, or indeed, compatibility with additional features the class has to support. So it has to be a custom built D-L-List...

...However I previously (some time ago) implemented a Head/Node method - it worked. However it become complex and difficult to debug as Head and Node shared functions. This time around I just want a simple, single [Readable! It's going to be shared!] class that somehow sidesteps the almost 'beaucratic' nature of C++. That means no Head/Iter/End copying overhead (and all functions/variables/debugging required for it) and no Head system with it's duplication...

...Static is the closest I get. Perhaps there is a way that somehow, you have Class A that stores the three variables, and a Class B that stores the list - and both of them are aware of each other and are able to communicate via some method/function (no pointer storage!)...

...Something along those lines. I am pretty sure there is some hierarchy or sub-class or inheiretence trick that would pull this off, and I need someone who knows the finer arts better than I do to, refine my raw idea or something.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a doubly linked list - one should have pointers to prev and next element, and it seems like yours is lacking the 'prev' part.

Comment: Could you describe the reason for this? Maybe a list isn't the best solution to begin with.

Comment: State what your real problem is, not in terms of your intended solution, but in terms of what problem you need to overcome. Why do you need something that is universally accessible but for different variables? (Do you mean that each variable --not its members-- is universally accessible?) How do you think that this will improve memory overhead? How do you think this will improve the processing times?

Comment: I don't believe you need this - most algorithms on doubly linked lists don't care about absolute position, but iterate over all items ( for example, you can't use a bisection search on a linked list ). Instead, make your doubly linked list circular, and implement the iterator so it goes round the cycle until it reaches the starting node. If you're doing something like a merge sort, you wouldn't be starting at an intermediate node but sorting a whole list after the first pass, and for the first pass the assumption is that the input is unsorted.

Comment: The example is 'bare bones' (hence //etc etc). The reason it's doubly-linked [template] is it will be used for more than one role. It's main role will be an individual node that holds a single char - so text files can be loaded into memory rapidly. The reason it isn't a 'singly-linked' is they can be notoriously hard to delete safely and quickly - you have to iter to the end, delete the end and repeat. That, and I plan to add an 'contract' (into an array, I.E. string) and 'expand' (from an array back into doubly-linked) feature for file-editing reasons.

Comment: @Pete - Assuming a doubly-linked array becomes as big as say... 1,000 entries [conservative estimate!], having to walk from one back to the start/end could be as big as 500 iters. I just want to be able to hop directly to head or end [without duplication into every item] and skip this. It's also useful for search techniques and deletion. D-Lists are slightly easier [I find] to navigate and to safely delete than circulars.

Answer (score 3):

If static variables are not suitable, you have only one possibility - use instance variables.

If you want to share the variables between the items, put them in the list itself and maintain a pointer to the list in each item as follows:

```
class List
{
    Item* head;
    Item* end;
    Item* iter;
};

class Item
{
    List* list;
};
```

Comment: Although it's a nice idea - the problem with it not being a single instance is that both head and end will be out-of-date in certain Node items - and iterator is useless in context. Although I could have misunderstood the solution.

Comment: It won't. there is one `head` etc. per list, as you need it. The items only have a pointer to "their" list, and can thus access the pointers you require. --- You could also isolate the three pointers in a separate structure, so that you only expose this detail to the nodes, not the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

Make a List class (as already shown by vitaut, but add a makeEntry() function in which a reference to the List class can be passed.  If List becomes more complicated, I would isolate these members to ListInfo, so the node only have access to them